# Resize widgets with clip in Gtkmm 4

Tags: gtkmm4

In Qt widgets have property clip. If this property set to true then child widgets (or their parts) that placed out of bounds of parent widget invisible. Is Gtkmm 4 have same feature or i have to make child widgets invisible after resize manually?

So far i am only tried to resize parnet widget. Tried nothing else because didn't managed to find anything. Maybe there is something but official documentation too incomplete and almost no one writes applications with Gtkmm 4. Code that i am managed to find does not use widget resizing at all.